# How to show Mathematica full output of a big Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I developed a Graph with 100,000 nodes and 402,000 edges. However, I can't see it because the output is truncated:

[image]

[image]

Also, when I try FullForm I get memory error, even with a 32 CPUs, 120GB RAM + 8 V100 GPUs:

[image]

Which are the possible solutions to this issue ?

Comment: You can use `GraphPlot` to plot the graph. Given the size of the graph, I don't expect you'll see anything useful.